# Unable to set value of input field

Tags: jquery, html

I have two input fields in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="search_category_id" name="cid" value="" /> 
<input type="hidden" id="search_category_name" name="cname" value="" />
```

I want to set the value of these fields using jquery and here is how I am doing that:

```
jq("#search_category_id").value(id);
jq("#search_category_name").value(name);
```

`id` and 'name' both are getting valid values... I checked that using alert.

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: jq(...).value is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just use `val()`, `value()` is not a function

Comment: normally it is $('Selector').val() or jQuery('Selector').val()

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Thanks everyone.... This worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.value()` is not a jQuery function you could use it with javascript object like :

```
document.getElementById("search_category_id").value(id);
document.getElementById("search_category_name").value(name);
```

But if you want to use jQuery Object you should use `.val()`:

```
jq("#search_category_id").val(id);
jq("#search_category_name").val(name);
```

Hope this helps.